# What questions on other Stack Exchange sites are of special interest to Jews?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, question-catalog

What questions on [other Stack Exchange sites](//stackexchange.com/sites) are relevant to [Mi Yodeya](//judaism.stackexchange.com/)? I'm thinking of ones that might be [on-topic](/help/on-topic) or almost on-topic on MY (or entire [tags](/privileges/create-tags) of such questions).

(But I'm not interested in [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73105) that's relevant only to [a specific MY question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10443), and linked therefrom, and not otherwise of interest. I don't see any benefit in listing such questions.)

Comment: Perhaps https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/87978/8291

Comment: [Jewish space lasers!](//worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/251606)

Answer (score 21):

Entire tags full of relevant questions:

- the [jews](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jews) and [judaism](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judaism) tags on the History site
- the [kosher](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kosher), [passover](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/Passover), and [jewish cuisine](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewish-cuisine) tags on Seasoned Advice
- the [hebrew](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew), [aramaic](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aramaic), and [yiddish](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yiddish) tags on the Linguistics site
- the [hebrew](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew), [aramaic](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aramaic), and [yiddish](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yiddish) tags on the Language Learning site
- The [jews](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jews) and [judaism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judaism) tags on the Christianity site
- [various tags](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tags) on [the Hermeneutics site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31216) (they tag by individual book and there's also a hebrew tag)
- The [judaism](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judaism) tag on the Islam site
- the [judaism](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judaism), [jews](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jews), and [torah](//skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah) tags on the Skeptics site
- the [israel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israel) tag on the Travel site
- the [israel](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israel) tag on the Expatriates site (think about those who spend a year+ in yeshiva in Israel)
- the [judaism](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judaism), [jewish](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewish), and [bible](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible) tags on the Mythology site
- the [jewish](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewish) and [hebrew](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew) tags on the Genealogy and Family History site
- the [the-bible](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-bible) and [hebrew-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew-literature) tags on the Literature site
- the [web-filtering](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web-filtering) and [parental-controls](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/parental-controls) tags on Super User
- the [yiddish](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yiddish) tag on the German Language site
- the [hebrew](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew) and [yiddish](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yiddish) tags on the English Language site
- the [hebrew](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew) tag on the Latin Language site

Some specific questions:

- [What's the best way to take a cold shower?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/34384) re the nine days (or the week of 9 *Av*) *from Travel.SE*
- [Is there a way where someone… Jewish… could meditate and take up certain Buddhist practices without actually [forfeiting] monotheism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3695) *from Buddhism.SE*
- [The land of gold described in Genesis](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/16770) *from History.SE*
- [Can a raven fly for a week or more? Or does it not mind wet ground?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/23530) *from Biology.SE*
- [Do Jewish people have better cognitive abilities than average population?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/8448/7156) *from Cognitive Sciences*
- [What is it about the education of the Jewish people that has allowed them to produce such remarkable Mathematicians?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/4064/1685) *from Mathematics Educators*
- [How can I make my kids passionate in science while being religious?](//parenting.stackexchange.com/q/19238) *from Parenting*
- [Is a complete global flood physically possible on Earth?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/4720) *from Earth Science*
- [Did "adding a sixth" mean adding a fifth in year-200 Aramaic? Does it now?](//linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12256) *from Linguistics*
- [Are the similarities between Tolkien's Dwarves and Jews intentional?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/92235/32466) *from Science Fiction and Fantasy*
- [Can aircrew order me not to stand in the aisle?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/49738/26164) *from Travel*
- [Asking to not present in a conference on Saturday](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/49134/asking-to-not-present-in-a-conference-in-saturday) *from Academia*
- [Should employer pay for an extra night abroad for Sabbath observance?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/54650/325) *from The Workplace*
- [Say a customer is an observant Jew and wants his site to be offline on Shabat - SEO problem?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/90967/10239) *from Pro Webmasters*
- [Kolmogorov complexity Chad Gadya](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78155) *from Programming Puzzles & Code Golf*
- [Understanding a medieval approximation](//math.stackexchange.com/q/1772724) *from Mathematics*
- [What is the optimal Jewish toenail cutting algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7769032) *from Stack Overflow*
- [Synagogue Scene in Der Ewige Jude: Looking for more information](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/34208) *from History*
- [How to typeset a complex layout like a page of the Talmud?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141924) *from Tex*
- [Is Judaism represented in the Narnia books?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/791/481) *from Literature*
- [Did Charlie Hebdo ever publish any cartoon satirizing Judaism?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15757/did-charlie-hebdo-ever-publish-any-cartoon-satirizing-judaism) *from Politics*
- [Why were these animals used to represent the different countries in Maus?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2101/481) *from Literature*
- [Why are there so many references to Moneylenders and Jews in 19th century fiction?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2041/481) *from Literature*
- [two questions about the Pluckeye time-delay self-control Internet filter](https://superuser.com/search?q=pluckeye) *from Super User*
- [Can sufficiently finely-ground matzo meal substitute for flour in leavened bread?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/80808/can-sufficiently-finely-ground-matzo-meal-substitute-for-flour-in-leavened-bread) *from Cooking*
- [Why was Cowen easily seen to have been Cohen?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3028/481) *from Literature*
- [How does one wash with sand?](//history.stackexchange.com/q/40081) *from History*
- [How do I remove Nikkud (vowel marks) from a Word 2016 document?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/32470) *from Writing*
- [How do I politely explain to my neighbour that I don't feel comfortable being alone with her in her house while my kids play?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/9309) *from Interpersonal Skills*
- [Something that has an end must have a beginning](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/33484) *from Philosophy*
- [Why are there no Jews in the Star Trek universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/193639) *from Science Fiction and Fantasy*
- [Tips for singing while dehydrated?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/11980) *from Music Practice & Theory*
- [Why is the fourth stomach (abomasum) of cows not used for tripe?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/93036/8291) *from Seasoned Advice*
- [Could the Tower of Babel actually stand?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/100765/) *from Worldbuilding*
- [Pharaoh and the Exodus as a metaphor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/6037) *from Puzzling*

Some answers of relevance:

- [Origins of “turn over in his grave”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/226478/73553) citing the Gemara *from English*

---

Please edit this answer!

Comment: I added Hebrew/Linguistics because of shared interest but (per our scope) those questions aren't on-topic here, so feel free to remove if you meant this to be more tightly focused.

Comment: I added the tags from the Christianity site because the Hermeneutics link was already here; on both sites some questions might be on-topic here and some not, based on cursory inspection.  If that goes too far I don't object to it being removed.

Comment: I added the sites that the individual questions are from, so that a person might get a feel for what kind of answer that question will have before clicking on it.

Comment: Why rollback edit 13, @msh?

Comment: @Shokhet, it's accounted for by the relevant-tags list.

Comment: @tealhill, Web filters don't seem any more in-topic than anything else Jews use because of Judaism does but lots of other people do too, like cups (used for _kidush_) and fingernails (used in _havdala_).

Comment: @msh210: Frum Jews use cups at the same rate as everyone else. But more frum Jews use Web filters than average Americans do. That said, I do admit that the Web-filtering tags aren't quite as strongly connected to Judaism as, say, the Israel tags.

Comment: I added a few [yiddish] tags, which is consistent with others adding tags/questions that are *not* on topic on Mi Yodeya.

Comment: @DoubleAA why did you add the tripe question?? See discussion above (in these comments) re filters.

Comment: @msh the last Kohein I gave an abomasum to just threw it out. Not to fault him since I had no better ideas, but it wasn't exactly the greatest Kavod for the Mitzva. More knowledge of how to cook it would probably be a good thing in the Jewish community

Comment: @DoubleAA, abomasa don't seem any more on-topic than anything else Jews use because of Judaism but lots of other people do too, like cups (used for _kidush_) and fingernails (used in _havdala_).

Comment: @msh questions don't need to be on topic here to be of interest